# socket.io isn't disconnecting on refresh?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am brand new to socket.io and trying to create a sort of mmo using it. However I've been running into a few issues. The current one is if someone refreshes it doesn't look like it is disconnecting the previous socket? In my console it shows the user as having connected twice and will create another listening for the same user.

This is what my console looks like after 3 refreshes:

```
User has joined : a
in getMap fora
user has disconnected
User has joined : a
User has joined : a
in getMap fora
in getMap fora
in getMap fora
in getMap fora
user has disconnected
user has disconnected
User has joined : a
User has joined : a
User has joined : a
```

client side:

```
  var socket = io();
setUsername();

function setUsername() {
socket.emit('add user', username);
}

socket.on('startMap', function (data) {
socket.emit('getMap');
});
```

server side:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var addedUser = false;

    socket.on('add user', function (username) {
            if (addedUser) return;
// we store the username in the socket session for this client
    socket.username = username;
        addedUser = true;
    console.log("User has joined : " + socket.username)
    socket.emit('startMap',{username:socket.username});

});//end add user

socket.on('getMap', function(){
    console.log("in getMap for" + socket.username);
});
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.log("user has disconnected");
  });
});
```

After 11 refreshes for same user:

```
(node:8808) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11       disconnect listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:8808) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 add user listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:8808) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 getMap listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:8808) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 updateMap listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

Comment: you have to broadcast the disconnect event too

Comment: This is apparently not all the relevant code because the code you show does not match the EventEmitter messages you show.  A browser will release all old webSockets eventually after a refresh.  If they don't close immediately, they will shortly.  If they didn't, it would be a bad browser bug.

Comment: Yeah, I shortly realized after I posted this the because all my socket handling was inside the router.get every refresh would cause this to happen. Had to do a lot of restructuring of my code but works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

you have to listen to the `disconnect` event in the `server side` and broadcast accordingly

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var addedUser = false;

    socket.on('add user', function (username) {
      if (addedUser) return;
    // we store the username in the socket session for this client
      socket.username = username;
          addedUser = true;
      console.log("User has joined : " + socket.username)
      socket.emit('startMap',{username:socket.username});

    });//end add user

    socket.on('getMap', function(){
        console.log("in getMap for" + socket.username);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect' , function(){
        // your action on user disconnect
      socket.broadcast.to(socket.chatroom).emit('user disconnect', name);
    });
});
```

Comment: socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.log("user has disconnected");
  socket.disconnect();
})
I already has this, is this the same or not?

Comment: where do you have that in your code? i dont see any.

Comment: Sorry there is a bunch more code, I was trying to trim it down, added about where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Check whenever user disconnected. Then do stuff there, remove from map etc.

```js
let users = new Object(); // Store users
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log("User has disconnected: " + users[socket.id])
    delete users[socket.id]; // User disconnected, delete from list
  });

  socket.on('add user', function(username) {
    users[socket.id] = username; // Add user to list
    console.log("User has joined: " + username);
  });
});
```

Comment: I have a disconnect event already socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.log("user has disconnected");
  socket.disconnect();
}); but I'll try your way to see if it fixes anything. Thanks!

Comment: Try `socket.id` when logging connection/disconnection. You will see that they are different each time.

Comment: Eventually though it says once I refresh 11 times that there is 11 event listeners for each of my sockets etc and sometimes hangs. Is that normal behavior?

Comment: `socket.disconnect();` remove that.

Comment: Still doing the same after that.